# \leadsto from right to left

Tags: symbols

`$‎\leadsto‎$`  cause

[image]

How one can write this from right to left?

Comment: What about `\rotatebox{180}{$\leadsto$}`? Needs the `graphicx` package

Comment: `\reflectbox{$\leadsto$}`, for it appears at the same vertical position as $\leadsto$.

Comment: @AlexG - Rotation and reflection will produce similar, but not exactly identical, outcomes.

Comment: The comparison between original and reversed is what counts ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Remark: Please be sure to check out [Heiko's extended/improved solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388688/5001) as well.)

Here's a solution that builds on and refines Christian Hupfer's suggestion. The two new macros -- called `\flowsfroma` and `\flowsfromb` in the following code -- produce very similar, but not identical, left-pointing squigglies: The first macro performs a rotation of 180 degrees; the second performs a reflection around a centered vertical axis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for "\leadsto" macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % for "\rotatebox" and "\reflectbox" macros
\newcommand\flowsfroma{\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\rotatebox{180}{$\leadsto$}}}}}
\newcommand\flowsfromb{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\leadsto$}}}

\begin{document}
$u \leadsto v$

$v \flowsfroma u$

$v \flowsfromb u$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\reflectbox{...}` is shorter than `\vcenter{\hbox{{%
    \rotatebox[origin=center]{180}{$\leadsto$}}}}`

Comment: @AlexG - Thanks. There's actually a slight difference. I'll update my answer to show both possibilities... :-)

Comment: The `\rotatebox`-based version puts it on a different vertical position than the original. So I would prefer/recommend the `\reflectbox`-based version.

Comment: `\rotatebox[]{...}{...}`, `\rotatebox[origin]{...}{...}`, and `\rotatebox[origin=c]{...}{...}` are using the center of the box as origin, but `\rotatebox[origin=center]{...}{...}` is the same as `\rotatebox[origin=tr]{...}{...}` and differs from `origin=c`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Thanks for this! I've updated my answer to omit the `orientation=...` option entirely.

Comment: @Mico The result of `\vcenter{\rotatebox..}` is vertically misplaced, because the symbol is higher than the baseline and is not vertically centered in its glyph bounding box. Therefore, the origin should be placed on the math axis and `\vcenter` is not needed. See my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388688/16967) that provides an implementation.

Answer (score 12):

Your symbol looks similar to the one of `stix` package, hence you could use `\leftsquigarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\[
\leadsto \quad \leftsquigarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, look at [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

Extended version to Mico's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388620/16967):

- Math style is respected.
- `\mathsurround` is set to zero (`\m@th`) to avoid additional
  horizontal space if `\mathsurround` is not zero.
- `\leadsto` is a symbol, whose horizontal line segment (or the arrow) lies on the
  math axis. Therefore, the rotation origin is put on the math axis to
  avoid a vertical displacement of the symbol.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\flowsfroma}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\math@point@reflection\leadsto}%
}
% Point reflection at point (width/2, math axis).
% Package graphicx is required.
\newcommand*{\math@point@reflection}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: math symbol
  \begingroup
    % Height of box 0 is math axis
    \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
    \rotatebox[y=\ht0]{180}{$#1#2\m@th$}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\flowsfromb}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\math@reflect@box\leadsto}%
}
% Reflection at the y-axis.
% Package graphics is required.
\newcommand*{\math@reflect@box}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: math symbol
  \reflectbox{$#1#2\m@th$}%
}
\makeatother

% Test part
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\TestAux}[2][\textstyle]{%
  \sbox0{$#1u#2v$}%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\textcolor{green!50!white}{%
    $#1\vcenter{\hrule height .05pt depth .05pt width\wd0}$%
  }}%
  \copy0 %
}
\newcommand*{\Test}[1]{%
  \TestAux[\textstyle]{#1} %
  \TestAux[\scriptstyle]{#1} %
  \TestAux[\scriptscriptstyle]{#1}\par
}

\begin{document}
\Test\leadsto
\Test\flowsfroma
\Test\flowsfromb
\end{document}
```

The thin light green lines mark the math axis.

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer the “old” symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{lasy}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{lasy}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> lasy5
  <5.5-6.5> lasy6
  <6.5-7.5> lasy7
  <7.5-8.5> lasy8
  <8.5-9.5> lasy9
  <9.5-> lasy10
}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Leadsto}{%
  \mathrel{\text{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{"3B}}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rLeadsto}{%
  \mathrel{\text{\reflectbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{"3B}}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\Leadsto B\rLeadsto C$

\end{document}
```

[image]